# measurement for car seat space

Tags: buying, child-seat

I want to buy a car and want good space for two car seats in the back. I'm not sure which measurement / specification correlates to it. for example a lot of online sources say cx-5 is tight while acure rdx has more space. however the "rear seat legroom space" official measurement is actually larger on cx-5. which measurement can I count on to quickly determine which cars are better for car seat?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about vehicle choice and not maintenance or repair.

Comment: The question might also be construed as a shopping query, which is also off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You want the hip room measurement, not leg room. Hip room measures the width of the seats.

However, the specific car seats you are installing plays a huge part in this. There is at least one brand that advertises the ability to install three of their seats in the rear of most vehicles, while other brands include cup holders and other design elements that make for much wider car seats.

You need to spend as much or more time looking at car seat options vs the vehicle itself, and be wary of feedback from people online since you don't know which seats they have.